# MS Azure Blob Storage Shared Access Tokens work for local IP, but throws 403 (Unauthorized) when another token using VM's IP is generated

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, unauthorized

I'm using Azure Portal to generate these tokens, while they seem to be working with the local IP Address, they fail when generated using VM's IP with 403. Infact, they seemed to be working fine a few hours back and suddenly started failing despite having a 10y expiry time. Here's the error:

```
RequestId:c535ade9-701e-005a-20ad-25a762000000
Time:2023-01-11T11:12:48.4496393Z
 {
  "name": "RestError",
  "code": "AuthorizationFailure",
  "statusCode": 403,
  "request": {
    "streamResponseStatusCodes": {},
    "url": "https://ubstagingcontainer.blob.core.windows.net/ubstagingcontainer/ubstagingcontainer/contacts.png?sp=REDACTED&st=REDACTED&se=REDACTED&sip=REDACTED&spr=REDACTED&sv=REDACTED&sr=REDACTED&sig=REDACTED&comp=REDACTED&blockid=REDACTED",
    "method": "PUT",
    "headers": {
      "_headersMap": {
        "x-ms-version": "REDACTED",
        "content-length": "59935",
        "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
        "accept": "application/xml",
        "user-agent": "azsdk-js-storageblob/12.12.0 (NODE-VERSION v16.16.0; Linux 5.15.0-1029-azure)",
        "x-ms-client-request-id": "6242a2d8-b8bd-4d72-bd5b-7ca9dc0d0ad8",
        "cookie": "REDACTED"
      }
    },
    "withCredentials": false,
    "timeout": 0,
    "keepAlive": true,
    "decompressResponse": false,
    "requestId": "6242a2d8-b8bd-4d72-bd5b-7ca9dc0d0ad8"
  },
  "details": {
    "errorCode": "AuthorizationFailure",
    "content-length": "246",
    "content-type": "application/xml",
    "date": "Wed, 11 Jan 2023 11:12:48 GMT",
    "server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
    "x-ms-client-request-id": "6242a2d8-b8bd-4d72-bd5b-7ca9dc0d0ad8",
    "x-ms-request-id": "c535ade9-701e-005a-20ad-25a762000000",
    "message": "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:c535ade9-701e-005a-20ad-25a762000000\nTime:2023-01-11T11:12:48.4496393Z",
    "code": "AuthorizationFailure"
  },
  "message": "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:c535ade9-701e-005a-20ad-25a762000000\nTime:2023-01-11T11:12:48.4496393Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error *"This request is not authorized to perform this operation"* may occur if you missed adding **VM public IP address** under your storage account firewall settings.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one storage account named **`sristorage12`** where I enabled access to only **local IP address** in storage account firewall settings like below:

[image]

From **local IP address**, I'm able to upload blob successfully like below:

[image]

Now I tried to do the same from VM's IP address, I got **similar error** as below:

[image]

When I scrolled down, I got **`same error`** saying ***"This request is not authorized to perform this operation"*** like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to add VM's public IP address under your storage account's firewall settings.

You can get your **VM's public IP address** from here:

[image]

I added **VM's public IP address** under my storage account's firewall settings as below:

[image]

Now when I tried to upload blob from **VM's IP address**, blob uploaded successfully without any error like below:

[image]

In your case, make sure to add your **VM's public IP address** under your storage account's firewall settings.

If error still persists, change your storage account's network settings to *allow access from all networks* like below:

[image]

Comment: I tried both - public access as well as adding VM's IP to firewall rules. The issue still persists. On checking the logs, I see this to be the reason:
`{"action":"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/read","roleAssignmentId":"","roleDefinitionId":"","type":"RBAC","principals":[],"denyAssignmentId":"","result":"Denied","reason":"NoApplicablePolicy"}`
Do I have to assign any roles? I'm using SAS token to access the container.

Comment: What RBAC roles you currently have and check whether any Azure policy is activated to deny the operation? Make sure to acquire **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role.

Comment: I've assigned the role of Storage Blob Data Contributor itself. I don't see any policy assigned that can cause auth issues.

Comment: I keep getting the same error as I've mentioned in the post.